# fortran sort - memory security violation

Tags: sorting, fortran

I am trying to write a program (by modification of another one suitable for 1D array), which sorts elements just in the second column of array (2D).

```
    module qsort_c_module

    implicit none
    public :: QsortC
    private :: Partition

    contains

    recursive subroutine QsortC(A)
      real, intent(in out), dimension(:,:) :: A
      integer :: iq

         call Partition(A, iq)
         call QsortC(A(:iq-1,:2))
         call QsortC(A(iq:,:2))

    end subroutine QsortC

    subroutine Partition(A, marker)
      real, intent(in out), dimension(:,:) :: A
      integer, intent(out) :: marker
      integer :: i, j
      real :: temp
      real :: x      ! pivot point


      x = A(1,2)
      i= 0
      j= size(A,1) + 1

      do
         j = j-1
         do
            if (A(j,2) >= x) exit
            j = j-1
         end do
         i = i+1
         do
            if (A(i,2) <= x) exit
            i = i+1
         end do
         if (i < j) then
            ! exchange A(i) and A(j)
            temp = A(i,2)
            A(i,2) = A(j,2)
            A(j,2) = temp
         elseif (i == j) then
            marker = i+1
            return
         else
            marker = i
            return
         endif
      end do

    end subroutine Partition

    end module qsort_c_module

    program sortdriver
      use qsort_c_module
      implicit none
      integer i
      integer templ
      real, dimension(4,2) :: myarray 
      myarray(1,1)=1 
      myarray(2,1)=2
      myarray(3,1)=3
      myarray(4,1)=4

      myarray(1,2)=11 
      myarray(2,2)=22
      myarray(3,2)=22
      myarray(4,2)=33

    write(*,*) 'Before sort'
    do i=1,4
      write(*,*) real ( myarray(i,:) ) 
    end do

     call QsortC(myarray)

    write(*,*) 'After sort'
    do i=1,4
      write(*,*) real( myarray(i,:) ) 
    end do
    end program sortdriver
```

There is no problem with the compilation, but it doesn't work. It just shows elements of unsorted array and then information about memory security violation.
Where is the mistake? 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add full error messages next time. It was possible to guess this time, but maybe not inyour next problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no lower bound for the recursion and are trying to subdivide a 1x2 array by the first dimension... A simple `if` statement fixes the problem:

```
recursive subroutine QsortC(A)
  real, intent(in out), dimension(:,:) :: A
  integer :: iq

     if (size(A,1) .eq. 1) return

     call Partition(A, iq)
     call QsortC(A(:iq-1,:2))
     call QsortC(A(iq:,:2))

end subroutine QsortC
```

Output:

```
 Before sort
   1.00000000       11.0000000    
   2.00000000       22.0000000    
   3.00000000       22.0000000    
   4.00000000       33.0000000    
 After sort
   1.00000000       33.0000000    
   2.00000000       22.0000000    
   3.00000000       22.0000000    
   4.00000000       11.0000000
```